# How to setup the Angular Routing

Tags: javascript, angular

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsosqn) is my work.

I set up a guard to forward the request URI /admin to /login, 
you may refer /admin/admin.guard.ts for detail.

It works fine. However, when the request URI is /admin/abc, it does not work.

The following is the /admin/admin-routing.module.ts content:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin.component';
import { AdminGuard } from './admin.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'admin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'admin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute paths for the redirect:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'admin',
  canActivate: [AdminGuard],
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/admin',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: '/admin',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }
  ]
}
];
```

If you use relative paths there would be an infinite loop of redirects.
From /admin/123 to /admin/admin to /admin/admin and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the order in which you have registered your custom angular modules under `imports` in `app.module.ts`. Make sure the module that contains a route entry for `{ path: '**', ... }` is listed at the end, after other modules.

For e.g in your case, keep adming `AdminRoutingModule` at the end in the app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ]
  imports: [
   // Angular in-built modules
   // Your custom modules
   AdminRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ ... ],
  entryComponents: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

`**` indicates the final option for url to be redicted when no matches found with exisiting routes registred with application. Also consider using absolute path in redirectTo property like `/admin`.

So I'm not sure if this will help with your problem, but worth giving it a try!